# Swift unchecked exception

Tags: exception, swift2

Since we luckily have exceptions since Swift 2, I wondered if there is a way to throw an unchecked exception. Sometimes it simply doesn't make sense to surround a statement with a throw-catch-clause because the error occurs only under very specific circumstances. If it's not possible, I would like to know what is good practice handling an error that shouldn't be checked for every time in Swift? Should I call `fatalError` which crashes the program or should I raise an `NSException` which is clearly not the Swifty way of doing it as I can't even catch an `NSException` in pure Swift I think.

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: We don't have exceptions. `do catch` evokes it, but it's really about [Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html). If you do want to avoid `do catch`, you can use `try!`. Docs: _Calling a throwing function or method with try! disables error propagation and wraps the call in a run-time assertion that no error will be thrown. If an error actually is thrown, you’ll get a runtime error._

Comment: Thank you, I haven't seen this anywhere so far ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you're writing a function and want to indicate that something internal has gone wrong (e.g. a precondition failed), `fatalError` and `preconditionFailure` are the things to call. Bonus points for using these with guard:

```
guard let myPrecondition = myOptionalPrecondition else { preconditionFailure("Precondition should never be optional here!") }
```

or

```
guard somePrecondition else { preconditionFailure() }
```